# Formulário com Ajax e PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

olá.
Eu tenho um formulário dentro de um modal - qual é aberto ao clicar em um botão que é gerado como uma coluna de uma tabela. Ao clicar nesse botão eu capturo os conteúdos de cada coluna e preencho um formulário dentro do modal.

Se eu editar ou não esse formulário, ele será enviado para um script php para atualizar os dados de determinado usuário - tudo via ajax.
Na função ajax, ao retornar success, eu estou comparando **se o resultado é igual a 'abc' então**, e se for, eu chamo a função Notify - qual gera uma pequena notificação.

O plugin para a notificação é: [Notify](https://github.com/msroot/Notify.js/).

Eu estou com dois problemas.

1. Ao clicar em 'Enviar' dentro do modal-form os dados são enviados com sucesso ao script em php. Porém, se eu fechar o modal, abrir novamente, preencher o form e clicar em enviar, a notificação aparece duas vezes. Se eu fizer isso pela terceira vez, a notificação irá aparecer três vezes e assim sucessivamente.
2. Eu estou recebendo os valores como parâmetro=valor&parâmetro2=valor2&parâmetro3=valor3, porém além de enviar o formulário, eu quero enviar um valor númerico, mas não estou conseguindo captar os valores no script php... Assim:

   ```
     var dados = $('form[name=ajax_form]').serialize();
     var arry = {userId: id, formData: dados}
   ```

Minha tabela-html:

a formação da tabela dentro de um while...

```
<td>
<button class="edit-user" data-toogle="modal" data-target="#modal-warning" data-id = <?php echo resultadoQuery['id']; ?>data-email = <?php echo $linhaAssociativa["email"];?> data-nome = "<?php echo $linhaAssociativa["nome"];?>" data-username = <?php echo $linhaAssociativa["login"];?>>
<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
</td>
```

Meu modal-html:

formação de um modal-bootstrap comum... e dentro do modal-body um formulário comum com 3 inputs: nome, email e nome de usuário... Ao final do form um botão para submeter ao script que contém ajax.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"name="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Meu javascript-ajax:
A função que contém todo o lance do ajax é chamada quando aquele botão que citei no início (a respeito de cada linha).

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-user', function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 var usuario = $this.attr('data-username');
 var email = $this.attr('data-email');
 var nome = $this.attr('data-nome');
```

O que eu pude perceber: Ao clicar no botão e abrir o modal e clicar em Enviar (que é o botão de submit do modal) eu consigo visualizar em Network/XHR a requisição feita certinha. Sem eu fechar o modal e clicar em enviar novamente, é adicionado mais um edit-user.php no histórico com status 200.

Porém se eu fecho o modal, e clico no botão pra abrir o modal novamente e clico em enviar, é enviado duas requisições e aparece dois edit-user.php + os anteriores no histórico! Agora se eu fechar novamente, e abrir o modal e clicar em enviar, aparece os anteriores e + 4 edit-user.php... Como se a cada vez que abro a janela modal a partir do botão ele acumulasse as requisições e enviasse tudo de novo!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa tarde, bem explicado, mas "TLDR". A ideia que eu tive é fazer um teste abrindo e enviando em um novo navegador. Se algo for diferente pode ser "Cache, Cookie, Sessions", posso estar completamente equivocado...

Comment: Se eu posto pouca informação enchem o saco, se eu posto algo bem completo, com o que eu fiz e até onde cheguei, apresentando os bugs também enchem o saco? Blah

Comment: Hehe, relaxa mano sei como é... Falei só minha visão, mas posso e devo estar errado(analisando o trampo que você teve para fazer essa pergunta), do mesmo jeito que eu parei para ler e entendê-lo, outros podem fazer. Fica tranquilo, malz ae...Num tinha visto por esse ponto.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá....

A questão de não estar passando os dados tente incluir um valor já no serialize, se a variável for "dados" faça o seguinte:

```
dados['userId'] = id;
```

Agora do outro item, coloque o seu código completo no jsfiddle e passe o link para analisar melhor...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6rLvfnLm/

Comment: E outra... Fazendo da forma que você citou, o resultado é undefined se eu visualizar no console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Eu concordo com o @VitorBraga e adiciono mais algumas coisas.

O tipo do botão é submit, isso quer dizer que ao clicar no botão ele vai enviar o formulário ao qual está vinculado à página descrita em action. No entanto, você está usando o JavaScript/JQuery para fazer a mesmíssima coisa. Isto é:

`<button type="submit" ...>`

e, depois:

```
[...]

$("#botao").on("click", function() {
    //Envia o formulário novamente
});

[...]
```

Isso só pode resultar em uma coisa: o formulário sendo enviado ao back-end duas vezes.

Outra coisa: coloque aspas (duplas de preferência) no seu código HTML5. E certifique-se de que está bem formatado. Tudo bem, é 2017 e a especificação do HTML5 diz que as aspas são opcionais para atributos que não são separados por espaço,mas browsers mais antigos podem ter problema com isso.

Outra coisa é que `serialize()` NUNCA vai pegar o valor de um botão. Você poderia poupar esforço e incluir um `<input type="hidden" [...]>` em vez de adicionar um botão com a propriedade `aria-*`.

Ficaria melhor assim, a meu ver:

`<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?= $resultadoQuery['id'] ?>">`

Perceba que eu usei `<?= /** Valor a ser impresso **/ ?>`, que quer dizer `<?php echo  $valorASerImpresso; ?>`.